# Contour integration question help

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to evaluate the following integral using complex analysis:
$$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{\cos(2x)}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$$
I have written it in the following form:
$$\frac{-i}{2}\int_{|z|<1}\frac{z^4+1}{z^2(z-2)(1-2z)}dz$$
However, the residue for $z=1/2$ is $-17/6$ whereas the residue for the double pole at $z=0$ is $-5/4$ and when the sum of these residues is multiplied by $2\pi i\times\frac{-i}{2}=\pi$ the wrong result is obtained (i.e. not $\pi/6$).
What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Could you please show how that was obtained? Because I have tried differentiating $\frac{z^4+1}{(z-2)(1-2z)}$ and upon substituting $z=0$ didn't obtain $z=-1/2$. In any case, that would still not yield the desired answer of $\pi/6$.

Comment: The residue at $z=\dfrac12$ is $\dfrac{17}{12}$.

Comment: @mrf that would indeed yield the correct answer, but would you kindly show how that was obtained? I am failing to get the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Res}\limits_{z=1/2} \frac{z^4+1}{z^2(z-2)(1-2z)} &=
\lim_{z\to 1/2} (z-\frac12) \cdot \frac{z^4+1}{z^2(z-2)(1-2z)} \\
&= \lim_{z\to 1/2} \frac{z^4+1}{z^2(z-2)\cdot(-2)} = \frac{(1/2)^4+1}{(1/2)^2\cdot(-3/2)\cdot(-2)} = \frac{17}{12}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Put $z= e^{ix}$
to evaluate $\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{\cos(2x)}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$
 we evaluate$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(e^{ix})^2}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$
,after you evalue this, its real part will be the solution of required integral
now,this becomes
$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{\cos(2x)}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$ =Re{ $\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(e^{ix})^2}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$}
and
$\int^{2\pi}_0\frac{(e^{ix})^2}{5-4\cos(x)}dx$=$\frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|<1}\frac{z^2}{(z-2)(1-2z)}dz$ (put $ e^{ix}=z$ and cos(x)=$\frac{z^2+1}{2z})$
so now theres only one singularity at z=1/2, evaluate it you will get that damn $\pi/6$

Comment: Same thing as what I wrote.

Comment: what you wrote seems to be incorrect. In any case, the correct answer is $\pi/6$ so it has to be wrong.

Comment: Which is again wrong.

Comment: The calculation of the residues has to be wrong as that doesn't give $\pi/6$ as the final answer

Comment: solve this way u will get $\pi/6$

Comment: I would like someone to please explain to me how the residue at $z=1/2$ is $17/12$.

Comment: solve through this new approach, it gives $\pi/6$

Comment: Regardless, I would still like to understand how that $17/12$ for $z=1/2$ is obtained.

Comment: @Grtv u have upvoted mrf, who just found residue at a point, which u could also have done. i gave u whole solution to problem, yet u neither voted nor marked as accepted answer. why so discrimination?

Comment: I sincerely appreciate your help, but it was not what I asked for. I needed to solve the above problem specifically using the method delineated in my posts (i.e. without computing the real part etc.). There was no discrimination, really. I am truly sorry you feel otherwise but let me assure you that that was not my intention. I thank you again for your help!